# Fetch different URLs and write to file

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to fetch different URLs e.g. site.com/page=1, page2 and so on. All fetched data should be stored in an HTML file to read it with Nokogiri.

If I only read one URL and write it into a file, it is working perfect. When I extended the script to read all possible URLs, it isn't working.

```
def getData
  @a=1
  array = Array.new
  while @a<5 do
    uri = URI.parse("https://exampel.com?pageNr="+@a.to_s+"Size=10")
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    http.use_ssl = true
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
    puts "Fetching data from "+uri.request_uri
    #puts @cookie
    request['Cookie']=@cookie
    response = http.request(request)
    if response != nil
      array[@a]=response.body
      @a+=1
    end
  end
  File.write('output.html',array) 
end
```

Comment: If you write multiple html documents into one file then that file is not an valid html document anymore, because it has for example multiple html, head and body tags. I am not surprised that Nokogiri fails to read such files.

Comment: oh right thanks . Was not thinking about that. So i will write one file for every url and than read eacht file with nokogiri

Comment: But how ? I only found Nokogiri::HTMLopen....

Comment: Ohh yeah that was exactly what i was looking for. Thanls

Comment: I deleted my comments and wrote a proper answer instead. I think that is more useful for other readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to write a file, you can pass the `response.body` directly to `Nokogiri`:

```
def get_data
  (1..5).each do |i|
    uri = URI.parse("https://exampel.com?pageNr=#{i}&Size=10")

    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    http.use_ssl = true
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

    puts "Fetching data from: #{uri.request_uri}" 

    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
    request['Cookie'] = @cookie
    response = http.request(request)

    if response
      puts "processing document..." 
      document = Nokogiri::HTML(response.body)

      # process the document
    end
  end
end
```

See: [Nokogiri Tutorial: How to parse a document](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html)

Comment: you can use, `5.times do |i| ` instead. or even, `1.upto(5) do |i|`